# Element selection from array

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have a list

```
index = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

and A is the array:

```
A = [[ 0.  5. 10. 15.]
     [ 1.  6. 11. 16.]
     [ 2.  7. 12. 17.]
     [ 3.  8. 13. 18.]
     [ 4.  9. 14. 19.]]
```

I basically want to create an array which appends the element of each row according to the index position in the list index.
So to create the array [5, 6, 7, 3, 4]. I tried the following nested for loop but it obviously returned the 5 values for each row, rather than the specific one from each row.

```
list = []
for i in index:
    for a in A:
         list.append(a[i])
```

Comment: Look into the builtin [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Are you working with lists or `np.array`s?

Answer (score 3):

Use the builtin [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate both `index` and `A` simultaneously:

```
result = [row[i] for i, row in zip(index, A)]
```

For added brevity, I've expressed your loop as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Manually iterating over the iterator produced by `zip` is also perfectly valid:

```
result = []
for i, row in zip(index, A):
    result.append(row[i])
```

Also note that it is generally a poor practice to create a variable with same name as a builtin, so I'd advise you rename `list` to e.g. `result`, `my_list`, or a more contextually relevant name.

Comment: Thanks this worked, and yeah the list is named differently in my code was just simplifying for on here

Answer (score 0):

The index of elements in `index` is the row and their value is the column, so using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) you can do:

```py
res = []
for row, col in enumerate(index):
    res.append(A[row][col])
```

Or as list-comp:

```py
res = [A[row][col] for row, col in enumerate(index)]
```

Comment: `enumerate` works, but I think using `zip` is more _pythonic_.

Comment: Yeah I agree that using `zip` saves the extra `A[row]`. I will leave this as another approach anyway...